# How do I rotate multiple proxies in selenium

Tags: proxy

The first proxy was applied as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "51.158.111.229:8811" # IP:Port

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://youbube.com")
```

How do I change the proxy to another ?

And how to disable the proxy?